# How to catch remove event in React-select library

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-select, state-management

I want to change the state whenever I delete an element from the react-select multi varient select option.

Answer (score 1):

There is a second param in the **onChange** function for *react-select*, where it captures the context, meaning it has information about what action is performed or what element got removed.

```
const onChange = (value, context) => {
// console.log(value);

if (context.action === "remove-value") {
  console.log(context.removedValue.id);
  const newState = newitems.filter(
    (item) => item.id !== context.removedValue.id
  );
  setnewitems(newState);
}};

 <Select
    isMulti
    options={options}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks mate, saved me a tone of time.